# SWRevealViewController unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

hello I am redirecting user to some other controller after user clicks the **ok** action button on UIAlertView.

```
     let successAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: Message.TRIPISLIVE, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) -> Void in
           let viewControllerYouWantToPresent = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyTripsTableViewController")
  self.presentViewController(viewControllerYouWantToPresent!, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
 successAlert.addAction(action)
 self.presentViewController(successAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

after clicking ok I am getting error here in the secondViewController where I am redirecting

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated);


         self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer())
        if revealViewController() != nil {
            menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
            view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }
}
```

The error is **fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

Answer (score 2):

can you try this instead of your code for `viewWillAppear`

```
   override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
            super.viewWillAppear(animated);

            if revealViewController() != nil {
                self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer())
                menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
                menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
                self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
            }
    }
```

> EDITED

you can add a `func` like this on your `viewController`

```
func customLeftButtonAction() {
        self.revealViewController().revealToggleAnimated(true);
    }
```

and then modify

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
                super.viewWillAppear(animated);

                if revealViewController() != nil {
                    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().tapGestureRecognizer())
                    menuButton.target = self
                    menuButton.action = #selector(self.customLeftButtonAction)
                    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
                }
        }
```

> Edited

you have to modify the form that you present your `viewControllerYouWantToPresent` so put this code instead

```
let successAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Success", message: Message.TRIPISLIVE, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

            let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action) -> Void in
           let viewControllerYouWantToPresent = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyTripsTableViewController")
    self.revealViewController().setFrontViewController(viewControllerYouWantToPresent!, animated: false);
    self.revealViewController().revealToggleAnimated(true);
            }
 successAlert.addAction(action)
 self.presentViewController(successAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: yes It works thanks.. But the problem is now the menu hamburger button doesn't working anymore on this controller.

Comment: could you please write a full code or edit mine. I am new so don't understand what should I write there

Comment: check now, I hope this helps you

Comment: thank you... what should I write here in selector place?

 menuButton.action = #selector(self.customLeftButtonAction)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114875/discussion-between-reinier-melian-and-hellosheikh).

Comment: now getting an unexpected  error here  self.revealViewController().setFrontViewController(viewControllerYouWantToPresent!, animated: false)

Comment: @ReinierMelian your solution throws this error: `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` for the following piece of code `self.revealViewController().setFront(getTokenViewcontroller, animated: false)`